# ADODB Recordset Field Value Returns Incorrectly?

Tags: asp-classic, ado, adodb

I'm currently troubleshooting some old code that simply serves up a file from a file share, and can't figure out why the SQL query is not returning what I expect from an Oracle database.

Here you can see the database entry for the file I'm trying to download:
[image]

And here is what the below javascript alert returns:
[image]

You can see that the Fields(index).value call below is returning the above value.  It seems to be escaping the backslashes, how can I resolve?

```
dim goCon
set goCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
dim gsSQL

'Define SQL here to query database and return frtFileName

set goRSet = goCon.Execute(gsSQL)
if goRSet.EOF then
    Err.Raise 1,Request.ServerVariables("URL"), "Invaild Report ID"
else
    gsFileName = goRSet.Fields("frtFileName").value
    Response.Write "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('gsFileName:" & gsFileName & "');</script>"
```

Comment: The *JS* alert will mess that up as it will interpret \ as an escape sequence - to test `response.write(gsFileName)`  instead. (or `replace(gsFileName, "\", "\\")`)

Comment: As @AlexK. say's you need to escape your characters before outputting to javascript alert.